# Proving alternate definitions of homogeneous functions are equivalent

Tags: functions

The definition of a homogeneous function $f(x, y)$ of order $n$ that I'm used to is $$f(tx, ty) = t^n f(x, y)$$ for all $t > 0$. I recently encountered another definition: $f(x, y)$ is homogeneous of order $n$ iff $$f(x, y) = x^n g(y/x)$$ for some function $g$. I want to prove that this is equivalent, but I'm stuck on the original definition implying the alternate one. I want to set $t = 1/x$, which would yield $$f(x/x, y/x) = \frac{1}{x^n}f(x, y),$$ or $$x^n f(1, y/x) = f(x, y).$$ That proves it, but only if $x > 0$. The original definition works for all values of $x$ and $y$ in the domain of $f$, including $x = y = 0$.

Is there any way to pick up $x < 0$? Or do I need to replace some restrictions on exactly how equivalent these two definitions are?